# Overlap surrounding borders in listitems while using css property of "text-align:justify" to make my site responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I was trying to use the css property of text-align:justify to make my site responsive. It is explained in detail in this article.
http://www.barrelny.com/blog/text-align-justify-and-rwd/

I have a small problem though. I need to make my surrounding borders overlap for listitems, even after browser resize. Kindly help if possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/aAkAK/

Html:

```
<div id="menu_wrap">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="index3.php">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="safety.php">SAFETY</a></li>
        <li><a href="careers.php">CAREERS</a></li>         
        <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li class="break"></li>
     </ul> 
</div> <!-- end of menu_wrap -->
```

CSS:

```
#menu_wrap{
    background: #a0a0a0;
}

#menu_wrap ul {
    text-align: justify;
}

.break {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
}

#menu_wrap ul li {
    display: inline;
    border-left: 2px solid #a60000;
    border-right: 2px solid #a60000;
}

#menu_wrap ul li a {
    padding:0 1em;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Im not 100% sure what you are looking for here .. Its seems responsive.. what do you mean by borders overlapping ?Have you looked into the css3 media queries ? 
@media only screen and (max-device-width: XXXpx) { csss : here; }
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: It is responsive. For the list-items, if you see there are two borders surrounding each item, with some space in between. That is not looking good. I want to remove the space between them, so that the borders overlap

Comment: @Pogrindis. I have attached an image now. This might help you understand my problem in a better way. Thanks

Comment: Sticking to to YOUR guidlines as to how you have already began this..  have updated the answer below, you are looking for margin to move it back towards eachother.

Answer (score 0):

```
        #menu_wrap{
    background:#a0a0a0;
}

    #menu_wrap ul{
        text-align:justify;
    }

    .break{
        width: 100%;
        height: 0px;
     }

        #menu_wrap ul li{
            display:inline;
            border-left:2px solid #a60000;
            border-right:2px solid #a60000;
            margin-left:-8px;
    }

    #menu_wrap ul li a{
        padding:0 1em;
    }
```

Try this in your CSS - One of the borders will overlap for you this way.

Comment: The issue with thia is that for certain size of the window, the borders separate. As I am trying to develop a responsive design, this might create issues. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/aAkAK/2/
But thanks anyway..

Comment: You are better off not doing your header like this then, advice would be to create a "divider" class, use it between each header "li" .

Comment: ya.. have reverted back to my previous code. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do like this instead?

```
#menu_wrap{
    background:#a0a0a0;
}   
#menu_wrap ul li{
    display:inline;
    text-align:justify;
    border-right:2px solid #a60000;     
}
#menu_wrap ul li:first-child{
    border-left:2px solid #a60000;
}
```

Have a look at your updated version of jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aAkAK/1/)

Comment: Thanks. The issue with this is that because <ul> is not text-align:justify, it moves the menu on my website to the left of my website instead of occupying the entire space on top of the page (which happens because of text-align:justify). Perhaps this is not obvious in the jsfiddle.

Comment: You can replace that text-align justify in #menu_wrap ul li into here #menu_wrap ul if you want to. In the jsfiddle I'm trying to simplify the code

Answer (score 0):

When you use inline-blocks you need to remember that your block elements are treated as words in a text... thus all font settings apply.

You can find out more about this here: 
http://joshnh.com/2012/02/07/why-you-should-use-inline-block-when-positioning-elements/
and here: 
http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

In your case you can set font size to 0px on the container and re-set it to something readable on your list items:

```
#menu_wrap{
    background: #a0a0a0;
}

#menu_wrap ul {
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 0px;
}

.break {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    border: none !important;
}

#menu_wrap ul li {
    display: inline;
    border-right: 2px solid #a60000;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#menu_wrap ul li:first-child {
    border-left: 2px solid #a60000;
}

#menu_wrap ul li a {
    padding:0 1em;
}
```